# Applying display:none in mobile/tablet view in html/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wzgsobz/embedded/result/) which is working perfectly fine in desktop view. On desktop view, it is working in a way that on click of any product item (as shown in the screenshot below), the description box gets displayed at the bottom.

[image]

**In mobile view I am  seeing all the description boxes gets displayed at the bottom without being clicked at the top**.

The snippets of CSS codes which I have used for the mobile view:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
.product-all-contents
{
   overflow-x: auto;
}

.product-contents .product{
  min-width: 50.795%;
  margin: 0 2%;
    padding-top: 3.91%;
    padding-left: 3.91%;    padding-right: 3.91%;
  }
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

At the moment. I am seeing all the the boxes getting display at the bottom even it is not clicked.

I have feeling that I am using **display: inline-block !important**  which is overriding **display:none** from the html

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
div.goal-setting, div.customization-tools, div.custom-invoicing, div.lead-tracking, div.email-marketing, div.royalty-calculator, div.brand-control,
div.franchisehubtv, div.cloudbasedtextipad, div.business-analytics,div.tech-support, div.employee-management, div.order-management, div.white-label  {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
}
```

I am wondering what changes I should make in the CSS codes so that I can apply **display: inline-block !important** only to one product item instead of all items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this jquery for all the sections

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   if ($(window).width() <= 767) {  
          $("#franchisehub").click(function(){
            $(".franchisehubtv").css('display', 'inline-block');
          });
          //add this condition for all sections 
   }       
});
```

And **remove this css** **:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
.goal-setting, .customization-tools, .custom-invoicing, .lead-tracking, .email-marketing, .royalty-calculator, .brand-control,
.franchisehubtv, .cloudbasedtextipad, .business-analytics, .tech-support, .employee-management, .order-management, .white-label  {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
}
```

Comment: going to do that.

Comment: Try it and ask if there is any confusion.

Comment: It worked, thanks. I will let you know if I have any question.

Comment: My pleasure. Thanks for appreciation.

Comment: @Khusbhu Vaghela It seems to work fine but only on click. I have integrated your code in the live [website](https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/franchise-operating-system/). It should work in a way, that without being clicked the contents should piled up vertically.

Comment: @Khusbhu Vaghela At this moment, the contents get piled up vertically only on click of product items.

Comment: @Khusbhi Vaghela I have put your code in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wzgsobz/2/embedded/result/) as well.

Comment: So what do you want exactly ??

Comment: When we take the website in the mobile view, the contents at the box getting displayed at the bottom should piled up vertically.

Comment: @Khushbhu Vaghela At this moment, it is getting piled up only after click.

Comment: @Khusbhu Vaghela Also, when we bring back the website from the mobile to desktop view the contents at the bottom remained piled vertically.

Comment: @Khusbhu Vaghela So my basic requirement is without click, the content should piled up vertically. At this moment, it is getting piled up only on click.

Comment: So you don't want it to show in click? you want it to be vertically piled up?

Comment: okay, I've checked it.. If you want it to be vertically piled up, then what's wrong with your old css?? which I asked to remove !!

Comment: Ok, so in my old css, all the information boxes were getting displayed without being clicked at the top. Only the one clicked should be displayed.

Comment: in my solution, the clicked item is being displayed only.. is that not what you want?

Comment: In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wzgsobz/embedded/result/), all the information boxes are getting displayed at the bottom without even being clicked at the top.

Comment: Your solution is fine but the items get piled up vertically only after click not before click.

Comment: @Khusbhu Vaghela Let me know if you need more explanation if you didn't get my question.

Comment: Try to remove condition of width in jquery...I'm adding another ans to show you may be it works

Comment: @Khusbhu I have no issue with the desktop view. The desktop view is perfectly fine. Only in the mobile, the content should pile up vertically without on click.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting all the boxes in the bottom to display:none except for the one thats active in your click handler. In that case you don't need the below css at all. I tried your fiddle and removed this css style and it works as you need in screen widths less than 767px as well

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
div.goal-setting, div.customization-tools, div.custom-invoicing, div.lead-tracking, div.email-marketing, div.royalty-calculator, div.brand-control,
div.franchisehubtv, div.cloudbasedtextipad, div.business-analytics,div.tech-support, div.employee-management, div.order-management, div.white-label  {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
}
```

Comment: If I remove the above CSS, I won't be able to achieve the desired screenshot for the mobile view. The fiddle which I have used is being used in this [website](https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/franchise-operating-system).

Comment: The reason behind using that CSS code is just to achieve the desired screenshot for the mobile view.

Comment: Is there any way we can pile it despite using `display:inline-block !important`  ?

Comment: I have provided another answer for you to achieve this by adding/removing class and setting styles for that class. You need not have to set a single style to more than dozen of selectors. Instead assign a single class to all these elements and set the style for that class alone.

Answer (score 0):

When you use !important in your css (external or internal) it overrides the inline style. So though you are setting it to display:none inline using jQuery , the internal style with !important  overrides the inline style.

You can add a class like 'active-category' to the div thats selected instead of setting the display:inline-block and a class 'default-category' to all the default ones instead of setting display:none every time. And then target the active-category class in your css and set the style

eg.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    div.active-category {
      display: inline-block;
   }
   div.default-category {
      display: none;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Can you update it in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wzgsobz/embedded/result/) ? In that way, it will easy for me to visualize.

Answer (score 0):

Just add jquery as below:

```
      $("#franchisehub").click(function(){
        $(".franchisehubtv").css('display', 'inline-block');
      });
      //add for all items
```

Try if it works.
Hope this is what you want.